# React Redux with functional hook (Unable to access action creator method on props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having a hard time debugging the issue, where it seems the Redux store is not getting connected to the React component. Below is the codesandbox link with the entire code;

https://codesandbox.io/s/crisil-tp7pv?file=/src/TestComponent.js

Really sorry, but I am unable to add the entire code here, as there are multiple boilerplate code/files.

Specifically, I am having issues inside the following function i.e. call to `props.saveTask()` is not working OR `props.actionCreator()`

```
const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    props.saveTask(task);
    setTask((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, timeField: 0 };
    });
  };
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the component instead of importing the **CONNECTED** component:

```
// The connected component is in default import
export default connect(null, { saveTask })(TestComponent);

// should be
import TestComponent from "./TestComponent";

// instead of
import { TestComponent } from "./TestComponent";
```

The same goes for `TaskLists`.

Comment: Thanks a lot...so you mean I need to import the "enhanced HOC" , but with { TestComponent }, I was not importing the "enhanced HOC" (but it was the base component instead which was getting imported)

Comment: Of course, how will it connect to redux store without it? Without connect you don't have any props passed to it